# Calculate divergence and value at P

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am confused as to what this vector even is.

$ v = x^{2}y^{2}z^{2}[x, y, z] at P: (3, -1, 4)$

What is this vector notation?

I know the divergence is this:

[image]

But what is going on in v? Is that multiplying by a vector?

Comment: You should know the notation of whatever source you're studying. It looks like $[a,b,c]$ is the vector whose standard coordinates are $a,b,c$. Now just multiply each component of $[x,y,z]$ by the given function $x^2y^2z^2$.

Comment: Okay so the partial derivative is `9x^2y^2z^2`. Can you show me how this was obtained? My course doesn't go through this at all.

Comment: Just write it out. The divergence will be $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^3y^2z^2) + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2y^3z^2)+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}(x^2y^2z^3)$.